# How do I debug Jrules in Java from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jrules

How  can I debug Jrules in java from eclipse ? I have specific Jrules (rule files ending with `.ilr` extension) in my workspace . How can I use the java debugger in Eclipse to debug them(step through) and see which rules in a particular rule file is being called ?

Comment: Ive always found it difficult to debug rules files. I know for Drools, there is an eclipse plugin that lets you debug.

Comment: Nothing special it is like a java debug you can even put breakpoints inside a business rule.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.6.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/debugging_topics/con_debugmode.html?lang=en

Comment: I don't think this debugger works with ilog jrules

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the rules in the following ways.

```
Start with a launch configuration
– Nothing to code
– Input data manually
• Use of a Java client application that embeds the rule engine to execute
your ruleset
– To automate or debug within a test framework
```

Answer (score 0):

With in application you can use the specific API's to know which rules are fired. Incase of debugging it can be done in rule studio where you can place debug points in then part of the rules and providing XOM as input and call the API's from POJO.